# How to return a list of entities with a given string range?

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

I'm trying to get a list of Vendors' names where the name starts with a character between A and E. Is there a way to do that perhaps using LINQ?

My current solution is just a very long if statement

```
var vendors = _context.Vendors.ToList();
var sortedVendors = new List<Vendor>();

foreach (Vendor vendor in vendors)
{
    if (vendor.Name.StartsWith('A') ||
        vendor.Name.StartsWith('B') ||
        vendor.Name.StartsWith('C') ||
        vendor.Name.StartsWith('D') ||
        vendor.Name.StartsWith('E'))
    {
        sortedVendors.Add(vendor);
    }
}
```

This works, but is hideous and I would love to know if there was a more elegant solution

Comment: Is your character range going to change in future? Or is it always going to be from A to E?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is a regular expression. For testing if a string begins with A through E, the regex is `^[A-E]`.

```cs
var range = new Regex("^[A-E]");
List<Vendor> sortedVendors = vendors.Where(v => range.IsMatch(v.Name)).ToList();
```

For a non-case sensitive comparison, set the `IgnoreCase` option when creating the regex.

```cs
var range = new Regex("^[A-E]", regexOptions.IgnoreCase);
List<Vendor> sortedVendors = vendors.Where(v => range.IsMatch(v.Name)).ToList();
```

To modularize, create a method that accepts the vendor list, the start of the range, and the end of the range. This implementation is not case sensitive:

```cs
public List<Vendor> GetRange(List<Vendor> vendorList, char rangeFrom, char rangeThru)
{
    var range = new Regex($"^[{rangeFrom}-{rangeThru}]", regexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return vendorList.Where(v => range.IsMatch(v.Name)).ToList();
}
```

Then call as `sortedList = whatever.GetRange(vendors, 'A', 'E');`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

```
var charsToCheck = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };
var sortedVendors = vendors.Where(vendor => charsToCheck.Contains(vendor[0])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear and readable I think I would do this:

```
string startsWiths = "ABCDEF";

IEnumerable<Vendor> query =
    from v in vendors
    where startsWiths.Any(c => v.Name.StartsWith(c))
    select v;
    
List<Vendor> sortedVendors = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pattern matching, it could be more intuitive.

```cs
_context.Vendors.Where(v => v.Name is { Length: > 0 } && v.Name[0] is 'A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D' or 'E').ToList()
```